# Normalize large datasets in PostgreSQL that is collected periodically and potentially with multiple duplicates

Tags: postgresql, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to decide how to handle a particular type of data. We have a probe that collects historical session details from a cloud service every 5 minutes. We use the returned data for analytics.

Since some delays are expected on the cloud service in terms of inserting the new historical records in their system, we decided to ask for the last 15 minutes worth of data every time we query them because we did not want to miss any data. So every 5 minutes, we ask for the records that were populated during the last 15 minutes. We have a few challenges now:

- There will be duplicate session entries.
- Each record will be returning with over 200 columns.

The columns for the records can actually be categorized based on the type of data they provide so we are planning on basing our normalizing strategy on this fact. But this creates another challenge:

- How do you normalize the data and have a way to still connect them together if needed with a proper key.

Right now we are focusing on pulling everything into a single table on each data collection. Last 30 minutes could be 1000s of records. And from there we will find a way to distribute it to individual sub-tables. For example, audio related columns from the record will go to the audio table, video columns will go to the video tables and so on.

I know I am not giving too many details about the data but I am hoping that I am making my point.

What kind of strategy would you recommend so that I can get a reasonable write/read performance from my Postgres database.

Note: The cloud service we are trying to integrate to provides communication services and each call may generate multiple records in the historical database. Unfortunately, there is no single field that makes a record globally unique. In order to achieve that we need to consider multiple columns together such as start_time, conference_id, conference_type, media_type together. I am mentioning this because I think this is also creating a challenge on connecting multiple tables together without duplicating data.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have outlined two issues:

1. detecting duplicates in the load data.
2. normalizing into separate but 'join-able' tables.

The first may be the more difficult. Within the data you need to find a *natural key* - not a generated key. (In a similar project I user the probe (actually a meter) serial number and the timestamp of the reading from the probe, make sure it is recorded and always processed in UTC as that is not subject to DST anomalies). If similar columns are not available you still ***must*** find a unique column or set of columns. Then you can either identify and not load the duplicated data or bypass it during the next phase.

The second issue is relatively simple. You create a 'parent' table to hold basic probe information like: serial_number, manufacture date, last maintenance, location, etc. You can generate a surrogate key or user a natural one (serial number). If using a surrogate make sure the natural one is declared unique. Then depending on you normalization create a separate table for each entity. The remaining set of columns used to identify uniqueness during load migrate to each table or alternatively themselves become an intermediate table. Either way the final distribution tables have a foreign key to the parent, either directly or through the intermediate. So using an intermediate you have something like:

```
-- staging table: date is not maintained after loadiing (at least not long) 
-- it will either be archieved or deleted. This is NOT permiante Data
-- but it IS a perminate table.
create table probe_staging
       ( probe_ident text                  -- from prob for id
       , transmission_time  timestamptz    -- from prob for id
       , captured_time timestamptz         -- generated
       , loaded_timestamp timestamptz      -- generated 
       , start_time      timestamp         -- prob data 
       , conference_id   text              -- ... 
       , conference_type text
       , media_type      text
       , constraint probe_staging_uk 
                    unique (probe_ident, transmission_time) 
       ) ; 

-- of course columns are just examples. But overall structure valid. 
create table probe_master 
       ( probe_id bigint generated always as identity 
       , probe_ident text
       , in_servace_date timestamptz
       , last_maintenance_date timestamptz
       , constraint probe_master_pk 
                    primary key (probe_id)
       , constraint probe_master_bk 
                    unique (probe_ident)
       ); 

      -- of course columns are just examples. But overall structure valid.
 
create table probe_transmission 
       ( probe_transmission_id bigint generated always as identity 
       , probe_id  bigint
       , transmission_time  timestamptz       
       , start_time      timestamp          
       , conference_id   text              
       , conference_type text
       , media_type      text
       , constraint probe_transmission_pk
                    primary key (probe_transmission_id)
       , constraint probe_trans_2_master_fk
                    foreign key (probe_id)
                    references probe_master(probe_id)
       , constraint probe_trans_bk
                    unique (probe_id, transmission_time) 
       ); 
-- of course columns are just examples. But overall structure valid. 
create table probe_transmission_audio
       (probe_transmission_audio_id bigint generated always as identity
       ,probe_transmission_id bigint
       , audio_data bytea 
       , constraint probe_transmission_audio_pk
                    primary key (probe_transmission_audio_id)
       , constraint probe_trans_audio_2_trans_fk
                    foreign key (probe_transmission_id) 
                    references probe_transmission(probe_transmission_id)
       );
-- of course columns are just examples. But overall structure valid.      
create table probe_transmission_video
       (probe_transmission_video_id bigint generated always as identity
       ,probe_transmission_id bigint
       , video_data bytea 
       , constraint probe_transmission_video_pk
                    primary key (probe_transmission_video_id)
       , constraint probe_trans_video_2_trans_fk
                    foreign key (probe_transmission_id) 
                    references probe_transmission(probe_transmission_id)
       );  
      
 ...
```

If you do not have the transmission time from the probe use whatever you determine as the natural key. I assume you can unique identify the probe itself from the data it transits. I have used the term prob_ident for this.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed explanation Belayer. I will definitely give it a shot.